# C++11 - I lost a move/copy assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

I posted this code in another question but I have a new doubt on it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class X
{
    public:

    std::vector<double> data;

    // Constructor1
    X():
        data(100000) // lots of data
    {
        cout << "X default constructor called";
    }

    // Constructor2
    X(X const& other): // copy constructor
        data(other.data)   // duplicate all that data
    {
        cout << "X copy constructor called";
    }

    // Constructor3
    X(X&& other):  // move constructor
        data(std::move(other.data)) // move the data: no copies
    {
        cout << "X move constructor called";
    }

    X& operator=(X const& other) // copy-assignment
    {
        cout << "X copy assignment called";
        data=other.data; // copy all the data
        return *this;
    }

    X& operator=(X && other) // move-assignment
    {
        cout << "X move assignment called";
        data=std::move(other.data); // move the data: no copies
        return *this;
    }

};

class X2
{
    public:

    std::vector<double> data;

    // Constructor1
    X2():
        data(100000) // lots of data
    {}

    // Constructor2
    X2(X const& other): // copy constructor
        data(other.data)   // duplicate all that data
    {}

    X2& operator=(X const& other) // copy-assignment
    {
        data=other.data; // copy all the data
        return *this;
    }
};

X make_x()
{
    X myNewObject; // Il normale costruttore viene chiamato qui
    myNewObject.data.push_back(22);
    return myNewObject; // Si crea un oggetto temporaneo prima di ritornare con il move constructor perchè myNewObject dev'essere distrutto
}


int main()
{
    X x1 = make_x(); // x1 has a move constructor


    X2 x2 = make_x(); // x2 hasn't a move constructor
}
```

In the main() lines I would expect the move assignment and the copy assignment to get called... but they don't!

MSVC2012 output is:

> X default constructor called X move constructor called X default
>   constructor called X move constructor called

And g++'s one is

> X default constructor called X default constructor called

http://liveworkspace.org/code/220erd$2

Where are the assignments?? I thought the first main() line would call a move assignment and the second main() line would call a copy assignment

Comment: I think the compiler is allowed to omit move / copy constructor call when doing "Return Value Optimisation" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: `X2(X const& other)` Thats not a copy constructor, as your comment claims it is.

Comment: Where _are_ the assignments?  I don't see any assignments in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Constructor2
X2(X const& other): // copy constructor
    data(other.data)   // duplicate all that data
{}

X2& operator=(X const& other) // copy-assignment
{
    data=other.data; // copy all the data
    return *this;
}
```

First of all, these are not the copy constructor and copy assignment operator for `X2` because they take arguments of type `X`. The first is actually known as a converting constructor, because it can convert from an `X` to an `X2`.

```
int x = 5;
```

This is not 5 being assigned to `x`; it is `x` being initialised with `5`. Initialisation, although it looks similar, is not the same as assignment. In fact, no assignment occurs at all in your code, so the move or copy assignment operators will not be used.

We can take a look at what each of the compilers you've given is actually doing:

1. MSVC

   First, `myNewObject` is created in `make_x`. This prints out `X default constructor called`. Then the `return myNewObject;` will treat the copy to the return value as a move first, find that there is a move constructor, and invoke it.

   > When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

   The return value would then be copied into `x1`. However, this copy has clearly been elided because we see no `X copy constructor called` output:

   > when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

   Secondly, another `myNewObject` is created in the second call to `make_x`.  This again prints out `X default constructor called`. Then the same move happens when doing `return myNewObject`. The construction of `x2` from the return value doesn't output anything because its constructor that takes an `X` doesn't do any output.
2. GCC

   First, `myNewObject` is created in `make_x`, just as with MSVC. This prints out `X default constructor called`.

   Now GCC does an extra optimization that MSVC isn't doing. It realises that it might as well not bother moving from `myNewObject` to the return value and instead just construct it directly in the return value's place:

   > in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cvunqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

   Then the same elision caused by constructing `x1` from a temporary object is performed as was in MSVC.

   The second call to `make_x` occurs in exactly the same way as with the first, except now `x2` is constructed by the converting constructor that takes an `X`. This, of course, doesn't output anything.

Comment: All right, I got the question wrong. So I'll delete, shut up, and +1 :)

Comment: Thank you but I still don't understand why the move constructor is called twice.. X2 hasn't a move constructor, whose object belong the move constructor to?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling I've posted my edit early so that you can read about the MSVC output. I'll start adding the G++ output explanation now.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling Done. The move is from `myNewObject` to the return value.

Comment: +1 Having [output from the X2 members](http://ideone.com/Gj2qee) would probably bring considerably more clarity to what is going on. And I concur with the assessment in this description.

Comment: Thank you all, there's a lot going on behind the scenes! I didn't know all this and isn't easy at all to predict the behaviour of the program if there's a compiler optimization inbetween

Comment: @JohnnyPauling There are not many cases where copy elision can occur. If you learn those, you'll find it much easier. See section 12.8 paragraphs 31 and 32 of the C++11 standard. :)

Comment: is the C++11 standard open to consult for anyone? I thought it needed a fee to be read

Comment: @JohnnyPauling You can get the latest draft for free on isocpp.org

Comment: @JohnnyPauling C++ is an evolving language.  Draft standards are free, final standards (and often standards near each final version) cost money.  As it happens, we are well on the way to C++14 (knock on wood), so a draft standard that is mostly compatible with C++11 is available for free, as are some pre-C++11 draft standards from before C++11 was released.  I'd generally advise learning from the C++14 draft standard given those two choices.

Answer (score 5):

You are seing the effect of the [named return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), NRVO. The following code

```
X f()
{
  X tmp;
  // ...
  return tmp;
}
```

can remove the temporary completely and construct it in the function caller's return slot. In your example the effect is like the function is inlined and constructs `x1` and `x2`directly.

If you want the assignment to be seen, you can write:

```
X x1;
x1 = make_x();
```